# angular js: Not able to pass value from controller to html of an included page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a header which remains common for all the pages. So, I included it in my index page like this.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="assets/lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="headerController.js"></script>
        <script src="HomeController.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header" ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
        <div class="main" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**header.html**

```
<ul>
    <li>{{vm.myName}}"></li>
</ul>
```

My **app.js** file looks like this.

```
( function () {

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'myApp.header',
        'myApp.home',
    ])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'homeView.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }]);

})();
```

I'm not including home controller or view as they have less importance here now. What I'm trying to do is, to pass a value from `headerController.js` to it's view `header.html`

As you can see, there is only one variable in my header.html

On the other side, `headerController.js` communicates with a backend service and fetches this result. And, I'm sure data is being returned by the service, I can see it in console and it looks like this:

```
{"myName":"Amelia Earheart"}
```

and here is my **headerController.js**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.header', [])

        .factory('myCommonService', function($http) {
            var baseUrl = 'api/';
            return {
                getName:function() {
                    return $http.get(baseUrl + 'getName');
                }
            };
        })

        .controller('CommonController', function($scope, $routeParams, myCommonService) {

            var vm = this;  
            myCommonService.getName().success(function(data) {
                vm.myName   = data.myName;
            });

        });
})();
```

Can anyone tell why I am not getting the value in html view?

Comment: try to put ng-controller="CommonController" in header.html ul tag. As i think its not getting access also u have to put vm in $scope, else vm is not access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should link your view with your controller.
Actually, your CommonController is not referenced anywhere. Try adding a ng-controller attribute to the div.header :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="assets/lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="headerController.js"></script>
        <script src="HomeController.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header" ng-controller="CommonController" ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
        <div class="main" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And also you need to bind the value to the $scope (which is your model) rather to `this`. Your controller should look like this :

```
.controller('CommonController', function($scope, $routeParams, myCommonService) {

    myCommonService.getName().success(function(data) {
        $scope.myName   = data.myName;
    });

});
```

If you want to use "vm" in your header's view, you can change the ng-controller to `ng-controller="CommonController as vm"`. This should do the trick.
If you don't do this, you'll have to update your header.html to :

```
<ul>
    <li>{{myName}}</li>
</ul>
```